# Push data in array after retrieval from Modal in Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I am retrieving data from mysql database by help of modal in controller. As there is query which will run many times and I have to store all retrieval data into one array. I need to store data data in following mentioned format while it is not happening.

Controller code

```
class subcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function Index(Request $req)
    {

    $arr=$req->get('myArray');
    $data=[];
  
    foreach($arr as $item){
   $entry=item::where('jobtype',$item)->get();
   array_push($data, $entry);
                           }

    return $data;
     }
}
```

Output

```
[[{"jobname":"Electrician","jobtype":"Electrical Wiring"}],[{"jobname":"Electrician","jobtype":"Electrical Work"}]]
```

Desire Result should be like:

```
[{"jobname":"Electrician","jobtype":"Electrical Wiring"},{"jobname":"Electrician","jobtype":"Electrical Work"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent actually has a neat little function built into the query builder. You can actually use an array in your query:

```
class subcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function Index(Request $req)
    {
        $jobTypes = $req->get('myArray');
        $itemCollection = DB::table('item')
            ->whereIn('jobtype', $jobTypes)
            ->get();
        $data = $itemCollection->toArray();


        return $data;
    }
}
```

For more information, check out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses